# How to position a fixed element relative to a DIV?

Tags: html, css

The problem is I have a *DIV* element that must be positioned in the upper right corner of another *DIV* always. It seems easy usign an *absolute* position, but when the parent *DIV* has scroll, the first *DIV* dissapears.

I have a simplified example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhzms/).

The goal is that the red text at the upper-right side keeps always in this position even if the user scrolls down.

Note: I know one option is use an iframe, but this is not possible.

Comment: Not happening for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Can it still be absolute but you set the position to fixed? Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/fhzms/1/

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but it is not acceptable, due the screen may have it's own scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Dont make the corner div a child of the scrollable div. make it a child of the body with position absolute.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it, could you put an example?